# What is the expected number of coin flips in order to get 2 heads in a row, if the probability of obtaining heads is 1/9?

Tags: probability

I am just wondering if this is right:

E[X] = 1/9 + E[X | H]/9 + 8/9 + 8E[X]/9

E[X]/9 = 1 + E[X | H]/9

E[X] = 9 + E[X | H]

E[X | H] = E[X] - 9

E[X | H] = 1/9 (1 + 0) + 8/9 (1 + E[X])

E[X | H] = 1 + 8E[X]/9

E[X] - 9 = 1 +  8E[X]/9

E[X]/9 = 10

E[X] = 90

Answer (score 1):

Seems right, equivalently let $n_H$ be the expected number of flips from the first $H$. Similarly define $n_T$.  Note that expected number of flips from the initial state is equal to $n_T$.  Now we can write

$$ n_H = (1-p)n_T + 1 \\
   n_T = p n_H + (1-p) n_T + 1
$$

solving for $n_T$ gives $\frac{p+1}{p^2}$